# How to create Windows Azure Media Services Access Policy without Duration or with a longer validity?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-media-services

I've created Azure Media Services and everything works perfectly. I've the below policy for all the `Locators` for streaming assets.

```
await context.AccessPolicies.CreateAsync("My 30 days readonly policy", TimeSpan.FromDays(30), AccessPermissions.Read);
```

I understand that the above policy will expire in 30 days and I'll need to re-create it. I want this assets to publically available for as long as it exists.

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Azure Media Services does not support infinite access policy, but you can use following example to set up maximum possible expiration time:

```
_mediaContext.AccessPolicies.CreateAsync("TimeSpan.MaxValue readonly policy", TimeSpan.MaxValue, AccessPermissions.Read);
```

Comment: This resulted in the following exception:
The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime.

Comment: Did anyone ever find a solution to this problem?